# How can I replicate the segmented lookup of the subaccount for a user field

Tags: acumatica

I'm adding a user field to the Order Types screen, which is an int32.  I want the same lookup as the subaccount field on the Sales order screen (field name: SalesSubID).  Here's what the attributes look like on that field, based on the source DAC:

```
[PXFormula(typeof(Default<SOLine.branchID>))]
[PXDefault(PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
[SubAccount(typeof(SOLine.salesAcctID), typeof(SOLine.branchID), Visible = false)]
```

I've tried using these attributes on my user field, but it doesn't work at all.  Unfortunately, as all too often happens in Acumatica, HOW this is implementing a segmented F3 lookup is a total black box / mystery, not covered in any training (not to mention how this field even shows up when visible is set to 'false' is a puzzle...).

So - the question is:  How can I implement a segmented subaccount lookup on an int32 user field to replicate what the subaccount field is doing on the Sales Order grid?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of the page so I am guessing you need to make your field in the page a PXSegmentMask

A snip of SalesSubID as defined on sales order page SO301000

```
<px:PXSegmentMask ID="edSalesSubID" runat="server" DataField="SalesSubID" AutoRefresh="True" />
```

Otherwise your DAC attributes look good.

Comment: I'll give that a shot.  Thanks, Brendan!